# Why Jetty Client is only having GZIPContentDecoder and not any other decoders for formats like DEFLATE and Brotli?

Tags: jetty

Why Jetty Client is only having org.eclipse.jetty.client.GZIPContentDecoder and not any other decoders for formats like DEFLATE and Brotli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip is a well spec'd standard that only has 1 implementation and is supported by the entire industry.

Deflate is deprecated by the industry as a whole.  Mainly because it has at least 3 (incompatible) standards for it.

Brotli isn't implemented in pure Java (yet).

Comment: Thanks @Joakim , can you provide reference for any RFC or documentation to support above theory that we can share with client/others?